# Failed to load assets when deploying symfony on web server: assets are not imported, failed to load resource error 404

Tags: symfony, deployment, server, http-status-code-404, web-deployment

I am trying to deploy a symfony application for production test. I follow many steps that I am going to explain:

1. First, I have installed the [CoreSphereConsoleBundle](https://github.com/CoreSphere/ConsoleBundle), in order to have a browser console. In my local configuration (windows 7 and wamp server apache), when I would like to use her I write this url `C:\wamp\www\myApp\app_web.php\_console`. It works well. But in my **OVH** *shared* server, it not works at all when I write `www.mydomain.com/web/_console`(I don't understand why !).
2. Then I follow the step of the symfony doc; e-g I cleared the cache `php app/console cache:clear`, and also for the prod environement with `php app/console cache:clear --env=prod`
3. I allow the debug mode.

`\web\app.php`:

```
<?php
// web/app.php

// …

$kernel = new AppKernel('prod', true); // set the 2nd argument to true
```

4. I check the compatibility server:

`web/config.php`:

```
/*if (!in_array(@$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], array(
  '127.0.0.1',
  '::1',
))) {
  header('HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden');
  exit('This script is only accessible from localhost.');
}*/
```

So when I display the url `www.mydomain.com/web/config.php` I have well the config page with no error.
And of course, after I allow my own `IP adress` and I allowed the `cache` and `logs` folders to `chmod 777` too.

5. I edit my `.htaccess` **files**. I have two htacess files, one in the root of my server and another in the web folder.

`/.htaccess` (root server)

```
SetEnv SHORT_OPEN_TAGS 0
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv SESSION_AUTOSTART 0
SetEnv ZEND_OPTIMIZER 1
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4_11
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ web/app.php [QSA,L]
```

`/web/.htaccess` (web folder):

```
SetEnv SHORT_OPEN_TAGS 0
SetEnv REGISTER_GLOBALS 0
SetEnv MAGIC_QUOTES 0
SetEnv SESSION_AUTOSTART 0
SetEnv ZEND_OPTIMIZER 1
SetEnv PHP_VER 5_4_11
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ app.php [QSA,L]
```

6. I make all config I need for the framework (database config with doctrine for my server, framework config etc).

All works well, e-g my application are deploying and displaying when I am going to the homepage. But my **assets** are **not loaded**. Indeed, my `css files`, `js files` or `images` etc **are not imported**.

**Where have I made mistakes when I have deployed the symfony application?**

I think I have to install the assets on the server, but I have no access to the **CoreSphereConsoleBundle** `console`, and notice that I have a shared server not a **dedicated Server**.
On the main page, my browser native console (google chrome) displayed the rrors for each script, css files and other client needles:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

I imported my assets correctly in my application, and in my local configuration it works:

`layout.html.twig`:

```
{% block script %}
  <script src="{{ asset('bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js') }}"></script>
  <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {'callback': 'fos.Router.setData'}) }}"></script>
  {% javascripts
    '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/jquery-2.1.3.min.js'
    '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/bootstrap.min.js'
    '@MySpaceMyBundle/Resources/public/js/hinclude.min.js'
    ...
    'http://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js'%}
    <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
  {% endjavascripts %}
{% endblock %}

{% block stylesheets %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/MySpaceMyBundle/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/MySpaceMyBundle/css/bootstrap.min.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all"/>
  ...
  {# animate CSS #}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('bundles/MySpaceMyBundle/css/animate.min.css') }}" type="text/css" media="all"/>
  {# dataTables CSS #}
{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I checked the bundle.
in it's installation guide, they ask you to add their routing in `routing_dev.yml`

```
#app/config/routing_dev.yml
_console:
    resource: "@CoreSphereConsoleBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
    prefix: /_console
```

since you have set the app ENV to prod, the routing in routing_dev.yml won't work in PROD .

if you want to access /_console in your PROD ENV , you should move that routing config they have given to `app/config/routing.yml`

Also the Bundle installation guides you to Register the bundle in the dev section of the AppKernel.

```
if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
    // ...
    $bundles[] = new CoreSphere\ConsoleBundle\CoreSphereConsoleBundle();
}
```

you should move it to the place where other bundles ( non dev ) are registered..

PS : once you do this , the console will work, but its a **serious security issue** and providing an easy way for any one to do what ever they want with your app..

that's why you should restrict this bundle to local usage. if you really want to enable this in PRO env, I highly recommend you to Configure the Security firewall to restrict the routes access only to Site Administrators

Example :

```
#app/config/security.yml    
access_control:
        - { path: ^/_console$, role: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

Comment: I am agree with you, I already follow the step for dev environement in order to install the CoreSphereBundle, I would not like to allow user or anybody else to have access to this bundle on my server. This solution would solved my problem for the 404 error concerning my assets you think?

Comment: it wont solve the assets issue.   app/console assets:install --env=prod

Comment: sorry my question was not formulated correctly, do you think, after enable the bundle **CoreSphereConsoleBundle** in **prod env**, launch the  ` app/console assets:install --env=prod` will solve my assets issue?

Comment: yup..if anything wont just. just copy the assets manually into /web ( last option )

Comment: I follow your suggestion, but it does not work, I make  the **CoreSphereConsoleBundle** in **prod env**. I have laucnch the command to install the assets, no error occured but it still not works. I have always the 404 error for the client side

Comment: I found the solution. I install the console in prod environement and install the assets, but we need to dump them with this command: `assetic:dump web`. I validate your answer because you allow to understand how install correctly my assets. I have one more question, what the command `assetic:dump` really does? what is the difference between this one and `assets:install --env=prod`. Thank you a lot.